# Regex: Return 5 to 6 digit numbers not preceded by phrase "IND"

Tags: regex, oracle

I have some numbers I need to extract using the REGEXP_SUBSTR function in Oracle 11g.  But I need to ensure I don't return numbers which are preceded by a certain pattern including "IND", "IND{space}" and "IND-".

For example, all of these I would exclude, because I would already have found these through 2 alternative patterns:

This has already found these items, so I need a pattern which looks for 5 to 6 digit numbers (with or without the comma separator) - but only ones which were not already found by these patterns i.e. which are not preceded by IND:

```
IND([[:space:]]|-)*[[:digit:]]{5,6}')                    
IND([[:space:]]|-)*[[:digit:]]{2,3},[[:digit:]]{3,3}')
```

I don't want these returned as matches.

```
IND-12345
IND-123456
IND-12,345
IND-123,456
IND-12345
IND-123456
IND 12,345
IND 123,456
```

But I do want these returning as matches as they are not preceded by IND.

```
12345
123456
12,345
123,456
12345
123456
12,345
123,456
```

Comment: Could you try `(?<!IND)[[:digit:]]{5,6}` to see if look-behinds are supported?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: I should have added, Oracle 11g using the regexp_substr function.

Comment: Okay, we give up on look ahead variations (which are not supported by Oracle's regexp).  What about just going after the 5 or 6 digits using anchors (e.g. begin and end line)?

Comment: The numbers may be embedded in a broader string, not always on their own as I gave my examples to be.

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020) do not support assertions, whether positive or negative, lookahead or lookbehind.

If you know that the matching numbers will occur at the start of the string or line, then use the `^` anchor:

```
^\d{2,3},?\d{3}$
```

Otherwise, you'll have to filter out matches that have an `IND` prefix using a separate `NOT` condition.

Comment: Thanks, although not clear how I would use a NOT condition in this respect?  The values will not always be on their own in a line, but could be embedded in larger phrases.